# Create CSS classes based on user role

Tags: moodle

Working with Moodle 3.9 and a fork of the current [Academi](https://moodle.org/plugins/theme_academi) theme.

I am trying to create a css class hook on the `<body>` element which is based on the user's role(s). I understand that a user's role(s) are context-driven, (maybe a student in one course, and something else in another), so I would output all the roles as classes for a given context.

Based on some extensive digging on the moodle forum I have the following:

```
// User role based CSS classes
global $USER, $PAGE;
$context = context_system::instance();
$roles = get_user_roles($context, $USER->id, true);
if(is_array($roles)) {
    foreach($roles as $role) {
        $PAGE->add_body_class('role-'.$role->shortname);
    }
} else {
        $PAGE->add_body_class('role-none');
}
```

Preferably I'd like this to run on every page. From within the theme, I've tried just placing this in just about every location/function I thought could be executed early enough to modify the body element. Either I get no output at all or a warning indicating that it is too late to run [add_body_class()](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Page_API#Base_theme_page_layouts).

I've had a skim of the [Page](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Page_API) and [Output](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Output_API) APIs and I still don't have a sense of how or when to execute this code. Should this be a custom plugin instead?

Comment: Another solution could be modifying body class with javascript (from php)

Comment: Unfortunately, using js won't address the basic issue (php) of getting an array of the current user's roles in any given page context.

Comment: I thought getting the user role with php and echo a js like this: 

echo "<script>document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add(\"".$userRole."\")</script>";

Comment: My issue has been that in the PHP `$roles` has not returned an array, so im not picking up the roles at all. So either the code is not be excited properly, or I am misunderstanding the nature of user roles or contexts within moodle. This is a question that requires a fairly deep understanding of Moodle.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with the $context var, try to use $context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $courseid, true); when you are in a course context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the header() function on the core renderer of your current theme template, for instance, on theme\YOUR_THEME\classes\output\core_renderer.php:

```
    namespace theme_YOUR_THEME\output;

    defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;
    use context_system;

    class core_renderer extends \theme_boost\output\core_renderer {
        public function header() {
            global $USER;
        
            $roles = get_user_roles(context_system::instance(),$USER->id);
            if (is_array($roles) && !empty($roles)){
                 foreach($roles as $role){
                     $this->page->add_body_class('role-'.$role->shortname);
                 }
             }else{
                 $this->page->add_body_class('role-none');
             }
        
            return parent::header();
        }
    }
```

This way, every page would call this function and have the desired css classes added to the body tag.